How can I set a default baud rate in TeraTerm?
When I launch TeraTerm for use on a serial port (like a USB port), the default (initial) serial settings are 9600 baud rate, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, and no parity bit. It's possible to change these via the menu with Setup->Serial port, but if you are connecting/reconnecting a lot, it gets to be a pain to manually change it every time you relaunch a TeraTerm window.
There is, however, a way to configure TeraTerm with a different default baud rate. You just have to edit the file TERATERM.INI. This file is in the folder (directory) where TeraTerm's executable is; to find it, right-click on the icon you use to launch TeraTerm and do "Open file location". In that folder, there should be a file called TERATERM.INI; right-click on it, then choose Open with->Notepad (or any other plain-text editor; don't use MS Word!). Search for "baudrate"; the line you find should be something like
BaudRate=9600

Change 9600 to whatever value you like. Then save the file; you may want to make a backup of the original TERATERM.INI first (I called mine TERATERM_FACTORY.INI). Then when you launch TeraTerm the next time, this new baud rate should be the default. You can also change the defaults for DataBit, StopBit, Parity, etc.
I tried manually setting it every time, but that grew old pretty fast.

What is your question?

Go to TERATERM.INI file, it should be in the same folder as teraterm, it has a default baud rate and default COM port setting, just change it to what ever you like.
